# Filtrar retweets usando a API do twitter

Tags: php, twitter-api, filter

Estou fazendo uma ferramenta de busca usando a API do twitter para receber de tweets. Entretanto, eu estou com um problema relacionado aos retweets, a cada busca que eu faço, mais da metade dos resultados são retweets. Existe uma maneira de eu filtrar os retweets sem ser usando '-RT' durante a busca? (mesmo com o -RT eu ainda recebo vários retweets que não contem ele)

Minha ferramenta de busca está em php e a lib que estou usando é TwitterOAuth.

Comment: Você está usando alguma lib tipo Twitter API PHP, ou fez tudo do zero? A resposta depende um pouco disto.

Comment: Seja como for, a resposta de um search é JSON e um dos atributos chama-se "retweeted", se ele for falso, é um tweet original. Lembrando que existe "old retweet" e "new reweet", o modo antigo era informal, o prefixo RT foi um idioma criado pelos clientes Twitter, no modo novo o retweet é diretamente suportado pela API, quero crer que hoje em dia os "old retweets" estejam extintos.

Comment: @epx estou usando a lib TwitterOAuth

Comment: Gostei, ela não esconde a natureza da API do Twitter. É como eu disse antes, procure pelo atributo 'retweeted' em cada tweet recebido via API.